# Cross-compile python arm

Tags: python-2.7, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile python 2.7.3 for ARM. 
I've followed this example:
https://gist.github.com/bmount/6929380

But during the last step with `make install`, I get an error:

```
running install
running install_lib
creating /_install
error: could not create '/_install': Permission denied
make: *** [sharedinstall] Erreur 1
```

This is how I have done my cross-compilation:

```
./configure
make python Parser/pgen
mv python hostpython
mv Parser/pgen Parser/hostpgen
make distclean
patch -p1 < ../Python-2.7.3-xcompile.patch 
CC=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++ AR=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ar RANLIB=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/python
make HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython HOSTPGEN=./Parser/hostpgen BLDSHARED="arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared" CROSS_COMPILE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=arm-unknown-linux BUILDARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
make install HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython BLDSHARED="arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared" CROSS_COMPILE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes prefix=../Python-2.7.3/_install
```

If I run this command with "sudo", I get an other error:

```
 Creating directory ../Python-2.7.3/_install/lib/python2.7/config
Creating directory ../Python-2.7.3/_install/lib/pkgconfig
/bin/sh: 7: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib: not found
```

Comment: What embedded Linux distribution are you targeting? Have you already looked at [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/)? it already provides Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.4 along with lots of Python modules.

Comment: Thank yegorich for your answer. I find the problem, it's just "prefix=../Python-2.7.3/_install" didn't work. I used "prefix=~/python". I didn't know Buildroot, i'll check :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use "sudo", not found the "arm-unknown-linux-", maybe you should add the path of the "arm-unknow-linux-" to the root's envirenment.